# Why is my server not receiving data from my client?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

As I'm learning about networking and io in Java, I'm slowly building client/server apps to apply what I'm reading on different tutorials. I'm stumped though, and I've been trying to figure out why my code isn't working for a long time. So I decided to turn to SO's infinite wisdom :)

After accepting the client socket connection from localhost, I have this on my server:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),Config.BUFFER_SIZE_NET);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),Config.BUFFER_SIZE_NET);
String msg = "";
byte buffer[] = new byte[Config.BUFFER_SIZE_READ];
int bytesRead;
System.out.println("Server is waiting for data");
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    msg = msg + new String(buffer,Config.CHARSET);
}
System.out.println("Server received: "+msg);
```

After connecting to the server, this is executed on the client after I press a JButton:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),Config.BUFFER_SIZE_NET);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),Config.BUFFER_SIZE_NET);
String msg = "msg";
try{
    out.write(msg.getBytes(Config.CHARSET));
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("Client sent: "+msg);
}catch(Throwable e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

After pressing the button on the client, I get this output:

```
Client sent: msg
```

On the server side, I get:

```
Server is waiting for data
```

If I debug the server, I see it blocked forever on the following line:

```
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
```

No exceptions are thrown. What am I missing here? I had it working before but I've done many changes and now I can't get it back to work.

Note: This is a slightly modified version of the actual code, to make it easier to be reviewed. If you think there's something relevant missing, let me know!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you have posted (aside from the horrible use of string concatenation).

Comment: Why would you buffer it yourself? Use [`BufferedWriter`](docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) and [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead.

Comment: Brian: You mean inside the while loop? Out of curiosity, why is it horrible and what should I be doing instead? Also, any wild guess about what could be causing the server to not read from the client?

Comment: Lukas: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that but I assume that's not causing the problem, right?

Comment: @BrianRoach Yes there is. He isn't using the length read when constructing the String from the buffer, he is assuming the buffer is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got out of the hole I dug myself into. It turns out I wasn't checking for the end on the data being received, so the code was stuck either blocking for reads, or in the loop that followed. By checking for a specific sequence of bytes in the data read by the server, inside the while loop, I was able to identify the end of the data and break from the loop.

I don't know if this is the (most) correct answer to the problem above but I solved it in this way, so I'm submitting it as an answer.